# How can call variable in function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have some data in varD variable following format:

```
[{period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 4, itouch:0},
              {period: '2013', iphone: 3, ipad: 0, itouch:90},
              {period: '2013', iphone: 1, ipad: 0, itouch:13}]
```

I want to call in my jquery chart function.

```
drawHeroArea : function (varD) {
        !verboseBuild || console.log('proton.dashboard.drawHeroArea()');
        if($('#hero-area').length)

        proton.dashboard.graph.Area = Morris.Area({

            element: 'hero-area',

            data: varD,

            xkey: 'period',

            ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],

            labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],

            pointSize: 2,

            hideHover: 'auto'

        });
    }
```

Data is showing properly in  alert in function. But when i add  `data: varD,` then it is not working please any one let me know where the issue, or how can call against `data:`.

This way function working properly

```
drawHeroArea : function (varD) {
        !verboseBuild || console.log('proton.dashboard.drawHeroArea()');
        if($('#hero-area').length)

        proton.dashboard.graph.Area = Morris.Area({

            element: 'hero-area',

            data: 
            [ 

                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 4, itouch:0},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 3, ipad: 0, itouch:90},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 1, ipad: 0, itouch:13},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:7},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:13},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:9},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:9},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 1, itouch:20},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:11},
                {period: '2013', iphone: 0, ipad: 1, itouch:20},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:19},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 1, itouch:24},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:26},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 1, itouch:14},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:2},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:3},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 1, itouch:3},
                {period: '2014', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:2},
                {period: '2015', iphone: 0, ipad: 1, itouch:16},
                {period: '2015', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:3},
                {period: '2015', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:25},
                {period: '2015', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:14},
                {period: '2015', iphone: 0, ipad: 0, itouch:1}
                ],


            xkey: 'period',

            ykeys: ['iphone', 'ipad', 'itouch'],

            labels: ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod Touch'],

            pointSize: 2,

            hideHover: 'auto'

        });
    }
```

Comment: @Mohit drawHeroArea(varD);

Comment: @Uchiha what do you mean...?

Comment: @AyazShah Whats the relation of `sql` and `mysql` with this post

Comment: Uchiha No relation ...

Comment: here its wroking fine http://jsbin.com/waxumuraca/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: That's why I have removed those tags nothing else @AyazShah

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
     proton.dashboard.graph.Area.data=varD;
```

The object being already defined should make it work